# Get latest records for a table that stores the delta of data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Actions`, schema blow:

```
[Actions]
ActionID
Date
Status <--Nullable, a delta column, only stores value when status changes
```

Now I want to retrieve the latest record, however it is very likely that `Stutus` for that record is null, therefore I want to get its last status change(ranked by `Date`).

Here is an example:

```
ActionID | Date | Status
------------------------
1        | 04/12| 'Bon'
2        | 04/13| NULL
3        | 04/14| NULL
4        | 04/15| NULL
```

and my latest record should look like: `ActionID: 4`, `Date: 04/15`, `Status: 'Bon'`

I know it's possible to do with nested select statements, but in my real table, I have about 10 of these columns, it will drastically affect the performance when a lot of queries like these are made. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Actions look like an append-only table. If this is true, additional table `LastAction` and a simple trigger updating table with latest ID and non-null columns might be beneficial.

Comment: How is the record with ActionID=4 related to the record with Status='Bon'?

Comment: Basically I want to retrieve that last record in this table, which is `ActionID = 4`, but its status is *NULL* , so it needs to fill the *NULL* with `'Bon'` because that is the last non-null record for status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your rules, but try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
ActionID,
Date,
(SELECT TOP 1 Status FROM Actions WHERE Status IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ActionID DESC) AS Status
FROM Actions
ORDER BY ActionID DESC
```

---

You said you have 10 columns.. How it works?

Like scenario A)

```
 ActionID | Date  | StatusA | StatusB | StatusC
        1 | 04/11 | DELTA_A | NULL    | DELTA_C
        2 | 04/12 | NULL    | DELTA_B | DELTA_C
        3 | 04/13 | DELTA_A | NULL    | NULL
```

..then multiple SELECT TOP 1 subqueries is still best choise I think..

but if it's like scenario B)

```
 ActionID | Date  | StatusA | StatusB | StatusC
        1 | 04/11 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
        2 | 04/12 | DELTA_A | DELTA_B | DELTA_C
        3 | 04/13 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
```

..then you may "reverse" your query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
(SELECT TOP 1 ActionID FROM Actions WHERE Status IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ActionID DESC) AS ActionID,
(SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM Actions WHERE Status IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ActionID DESC) AS Date,
StatusA,
StatusB,
StatusC
FROM Actions
WHERE StatusA IS NOT NULL -- then StatusB and StatusC are also NOT NULL
ORDER BY ActionID DESC
```

..but be aware you may get empty result if there is no row with StatusA = NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks, That is my current solution. But I wish to avoid too many nested select statements. because I have about 10 columns like these and they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have expanded my example queries above.. Look at them now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, although i'm not sure whether or not i've understood your requirement:

```
WITH Actions AS(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order By Date DESC)AS DateRank
        , ActionsID
        , Date
        , Status
    FROM [Actions]
)
SELECT TOP 1 a1.ActionsID,a1.Date,a2.Status 
FROM Actions a1 INNER JOIN Actions a2 
    ON a1.DateRank < a2.DateRank AND a2.Status IS NOT NULL
WHERE a1.DateRank=1
```

Comment: Note that the TOP clause is redundant since i'm selection only the last record anyway(`a1.DateRank=1`).